# Can't get the encoding to use UTF-8, even with the <metadata> tag?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I converted a Joomla 1.5 site to 2.5, and just about everything is going well, but I'm fighting the display of a character. On the live site there is text like `“You Agency guys are twisted.”`, and it displays fine, but on the converted site that same database article displays like `�You Agency guys are twisted.�`.

Now, I've verified that the two elements have the exact same *computed style*. But it feels like a font issue. Is it maybe an issue with how Joomla 2.5 encodes that character?

## Edit 1

After the comments I went and verified the databse. I found that the `character_set_database` for the old database was `latin1` and not `utf8`, so I ran this statement:

```
alter database my_database default charset latin1;
```

and now all character set variables line up between the two database. Further, I verified that the character set for the page is `utf-8` because it's emitting this `<metadata>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

However, the characters still aren't displaying properly.

## Edit 2

I've also tried setting my `default_charset` to `utf-8` for PHP:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Before adding that line there wasn't even a setting, so it would be the Apache default I'm guessing.

## Edit 3

I've now also verified that the `index.php` file has a `Content-Type` header of `text/html; charset=utf-8`. But alas, these special characters still aren't displaying right.

Comment: I think that's more an issue with Unicode encoding (UTF-8 vs UTF-16 vs UCS-2?)

Comment: Those aren't double-quotes. they "smart quotes", "typographic quotes", blah blah. Getting `�` means you've got a character set mismatch somewhere, e.g. outputting UTF-8 characters in an ISO-8859-1 environment.

Comment: @MarcB, are you speaking specifically at the database level (e.g. I need to modify some properties on the database)?

Comment: The entire rendering chain: client->server->database->server->client and all software stages within MUST be set to use the same character set, or at least connected with the appropriate charset conversion logic. If any stage is using a different charset, then you're going to get "trashed" strings like this.

Comment: Also make sure that there is no charset being set in the HTTP header. The HTTP header always overrides the `<meta>` settings in the file itself.

Comment: I doubt that a php file has `application/javascript` for a MIME type. Are you sure you're looking at the right http header?

Comment: do you use "SET NAMES utf8" as your first query?

Comment: @null.point3r, when you says `...as your first query?`, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @TheSolution I mean use this query after create connection to mySql. sry for my english :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running this query before anything else:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

The last time I had problems with character sets it was because even though everything else was in UTF-8 (the HTML being served, the code I wrote, the database tables, etc.), the database **connection** was still passing everything in another charset. This should fix that.

**Edit:** as mentioned by @null.point3r below, using the following code is a better alternative because escaped strings might otherwise still use the wrong encoding:

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')
```

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Comment: @neoistheone. it is better to use `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` because of SQL injection.read more: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Comment: @null, this statement isn't subject to SQL injection. It's a static statement that is run immediately after making the global connection, therewith no user input can even be provided to issue a SQL injection attack.

Comment: @neoistheone,`...The character set should be understood and defined, as it has an affect on every action, and includes security implications. For example, the escaping mechanism (e.g., mysqli_real_escape_string() for mysqli, mysql_real_escape_string() for mysql, and PDO::quote() for PDO_MySQL) will adhere to this setting. It is important to realize that these functions will not use the character set that is defined with a query...`

Comment: I was not aware there is a PHP-wrapper for this. Guess I learned something new too. In my defense: the framework I use does not use these escape functions and has its own way of handling escaping.

Answer (score 5):

MarcB's comment is exactly right - the encoding must be the same throughout each layer.  To debug this, you're going to need to find which layer has an incorrect encoding.

Do this:

Search through your PHP source code and find the line that does the actual call to select the content from MySQL.

At that point, hex encode the string and see what the raw bytes are.  For example:

```
// temp, debugging
print("TEST:".bin2hex($whatever_field_value));
die();
```

See what you get.  A correctly encoded left UTF-8 "smart quote" would give: `e2809c`.  If it instead gives you a single byte or other value, then it's not UTF-8.  At which point you'd know that the encoding problem is somewhere between the PHP mysqli call and the database (check the charset of the mysql field, if any explicitly set, the default charset for the table, and the charset for the connection - see [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php))

(NOTE: You can easily see the UTF-8 encoding for a character by saving it in a text file as UTF-8 and then opening it with any binary editor or using `hexdump -C` on Mac/Linux.  [Beware of the UTF-8 Byte Order Mark - `efbbbf` - that some editors put at the front of files, that's not what you're looking for, ignore that])

If it *is* correct at that point, then do the same test again right before the text gets output (probably in one of the Joomla template files).  See if it is correct there.

Then to test it at the browser level, wget (or curl or whatever) the page:

```
wget http://yoursitename/ -O test.html
```

([wget Windows users](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm))

Do `hexdump -C` (or open in binary editor) on the results and find the place where that quote should be and see what the raw bytes are.

As mentioned already, the Content-type HTTP header and the meta content-type tag need to match the encoding you are using (UTF-8) - so check that as well (`wget -S` will show you the headers).  But, realize that not only do your headers and meta tags need to say UTF-8, but the data must actually be encoded as UTF-8 - which is why you need to check it as above.

That will tell you what you need to know to narrow down your problem, at which point you might already know what you need to do to fix, or at least what specific part of the setup is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to export your current database, let's do this with

`# mysqldump -uroot -p databasename > database.sql`

Then you need to convert your latin1 data to utf8, let's do that with

`# iconv -f 'latin1' -t 'utf-8' database.sql > database_utf8.sql`

then, import data back

`# mysql -uroot -p databasename < database_utf8.sql`

Since you have already taken care of output encoding and mysql connection/collation, you should see proper characters served via your apache :)